# Convert JSON array to Object Array - Apache camel

Tags: java, arrays, json, groovy, apache-camel

```
[
  {
    "Name": "ABC", 
    "ID": 1,
    "StartDate": 1444845395112,
    "EndDate": null,
    "ValueAction": null,
    "ValueSource": "lmn"
  }, 
  {
    "Name": "PQR", 
    "ID": 2,
    "StartDate": 1444845395119,
    "EndDate": 1446845395119,
    "ValueAction": null,
    "ValueSource": null
  }, 
  {
    "Name": "XYZ", 
    "ID": 3,
    "StartDate": null,
    "EndDate": null,
    "ValueAction": "qwe",
    "ValueSource": "lmn"
  }
]
```

How to create object array from this json using split with 'groovy script/java'

[Name, ID, ValueAction, ValueSource] here ValueAction/ValueSource should be null if StartDate is null. So array should be like this.

```
 [[ABC,1, , lmn],[PQR,2, , ],[XYZ,3, , ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import groovy.json.*

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''[
  {
    "Name": "ABC",
    "ID": 1,
    "StartDate": 1444845395112,
    "EndDate": null,
    "ValueAction": null,
    "ValueSource": "lmn"
  },
  {
    "Name": "PQR",
    "ID": 2,
    "StartDate": 1444845395119,
    "EndDate": 1446845395119,
    "ValueAction": null,
    "ValueSource": null
  },
  {
    "Name": "XYZ",
    "ID": 3,
    "StartDate": null,
    "EndDate": null,
    "ValueAction": "qwe",
    "ValueSource": "lmn"
  }
]
'''

def res = json.findResults{ it.StartDate ? [ it.Name, it.ID, it.ValueAction ?: '', it.ValueSource ] : null }

assert res.toString() == '[[ABC, 1, , lmn], [PQR, 2, , null]]'
```

Next time please post the valid JSON.

Comment: If they need `null` as in the question, then they can also do `json.collect { it.Name, it.ID, it.StartDate ? it.ValueAction : null, it.StartDate ? it.ValueSource : null] }`.  But as you say, valid Json always helps 